# Why is mat-sort-header not working in this case?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, mat-table

I am working on displaying a table with sorting using angular material. I am able to get the sorted data for columns: 'customer name' and 'Validity Date' but the **column='Route' is not getting sorted**. This is my code,
In html:

```
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="width100">
         <ng-container matColumnDef="customerName">
             <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Customer Name </th>
             <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customerName}} </td>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-container matColumnDef="validityDate">
              <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell> Validity Date </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dateOfValidity | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}} </td>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-container matColumnDef="route">
              <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell> Route </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.oPortCountryCode}}, {{row.oPortCode}} >>
                        {{row.dPortCountryCode}}, {{row.dPortCode}}</td>
         </ng-container> 
   </table>
```

In .ts file:

```
public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<QuotationModel>;
ngOnInit() {
this.service.getList().subscribe(resp => {
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<QuotationModel>(resp.items);
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
                switch (property) {
                    case 'validityDate':
                        const newDate = new Date(item.dateOfValidity);
                        return newDate;
                    default:
                    return item[property];
                }
            }; 
});
}
```

And the model is:

```
export interface QuotationModel{
customerName: string;
dateOfValidity: Date;
oPortCountryCode: string;
oPortCode:string;
dPortCountryCode:string;
dPortCode:string;
}
```

Comment: try and assign matColumnDef to the same propertyname as your quotationmodel
validityDate => dateOfValidity etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the sorting accessor will try to sort by the property `route` as it is your matColumnDef. Add a case to your sorting accessor which returns the same value as you display and it will sort by this column alphabetical.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getList().subscribe(resp => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<QuotationModel>(resp.items);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'validityDate':
          const newDate = new Date(item.dateOfValidity);
          return newDate;
        case 'route':
          return item.oPortCountryCode + ", " + item.oPortCode + " >> " + item.dPortCountryCode + ", " + item.dPortCode;
        default:
          return item[property];
      }
    }; 
  });
}
```